# Is there a way to add embedded python code to Markdown?

Tags: python, markdown

There is a way to add R code to Markdown (Rmd) by using

````
```{r}
foo()
```
````

The result will be shown as a block of code and the output of that code (that will be calculated dynamically).

Can the same thing be done for Python or for that matter any other language?

Comment: What do you mean by "add embedded Python code"? Do you want the code to actually be executed? Or just formatted correctly and included in the HTML?

Comment: I want to execute the code. I added the word 'execute' to the question, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 11):

you can simply use:

````
```python 
your_code = do_some_stuff
```
````

And yes, you can do the same for a long list of languages. You can check the list of languages supported in this link: https://rdmd.readme.io/docs/code-blocks

Answer (score 3):

you can embed python into .Rmd as well, see https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/023-engine-python.Rmd for examples

Answer (score 2):

[`marky`](https://github.com/lehmann7/marky) is Markdown preprocessor allowing to execute embedded python code in Markdown documents. Documents are rendered in `pdf` and `html` using `pandoc`. All steps are implemented in a `Makefile`.